# comparing vectors both by value and order

Tags: r, vector, comparison

I have extracted some baseball batting lineups in the form of character vectors 
e.g

```
[1] "Yunel Escobar"     "Kelly Johnson"     "Jose Bautista"     "Adam Lind"        
[5] "Edwin Encarnacion" "Brett Lawrie"      "Eric Thames"       "Colby Rasmus"     
[9] "Jeff Mathis"
```

and created a dataframe, allLineups, in R which lists the batting order for every game in a 162 game season

head(allLineups)

```
player          order game
 Yunel Escobar     1    1
 Kelly Johnson     2    1
 Jose Bautista     3    1
 Adam Lind         4    1
 Edwin Encarnacion 5    1
 Brett Lawrie      6    1
```

I now want to do some analysis which would include the following

a) How often during the season is any particular group of  9 players in the batting lineup

b) How many times does the exact same lineup (inc order) occur

c) How often do two specified players appear together

d) For any specified game, how does it's lineup compare with that of ,say, the first game

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to approach answering these queries

Comment: Look at the package [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html).

Comment: Could you a bit more specific. I have used plyr a bit and for  summarization of say how many times a player played in a particular order in the lineup across e.g. teams and seasons I would use it  but am having trouble seeing how to apply it for the sort of questions I am looking at

Comment: @csgillespie. well if I had just a couple of character vectors e.g. lineup1 and lineup2 then the setdiff function might be useful but I am not sure how i can get to that in an dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `sort` calls to deliver what the OP is requesting in the comment below;

```
player <- c("Yunel Escobar"  ,   "Kelly Johnson"  ,   "Jose Bautista"   ,  "Adam Lind"   ,     
"Edwin Encarnacion", "Brett Lawrie"   ,   "Eric Thames"   ,    "Colby Rasmus"    , 
"Jeff Mathis")

# create two games with different lineups
allLineups <- data.frame(player=c(player, rev(player)) , order=1:9, game=rep(1:2, each=9))

#construct a lineup
with(allLineups, tapply(player, game, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse="/") ) )

# tabulate the values for lineups
table( with(allLineups, tapply(player, game, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse="/") ) ) )
```

You can shorten up the lineup listing by working with:

```
allLineups$shortplyr <- sub("^(.).+\\ (.{4}).*$", '\\1_\\2', allLineups$player)
# ------------
table( with(allLineups, tapply(shortplyr, game, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse="/") ) ) )

A_Lind/B_Lawr/C_Rasm/E_Enca/E_Tham/J_Baut/J_Math/K_John/Y_Esco 
                                                             2
```

And the OP cleaarly does not want this.:

And if the lineups are not ordered, you should sort with:

```
allLineups <- with( allLinups, allLineups[ order(game, order) , ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. As I understand it, this does allow me to aggregate the exact same lineup occurs i.e. my b) above. In your example this would be 1 of each.

Comment: However, it would not appear to help to see when same 9 players appear but bat in a different order - in your example both lineups should be the same for this query.  I guess there might be another way to get this (length of the concatenated names would likely catch most results but not be 100% sure) but I was certainly expecting R to throw up a more elegant solution

Comment: Then define the problem and desired solution better. If you want the lineups without regard to the batting "order", all you need to do is make that aspect clear. We'll sort by name and then permutations will get considered as the same "lineup". As Jim Holtman's tag line says" "What problem are you trying to solve?" (You should clarify this by editing your questions, not in the comments.)

Comment: For me the b) item with phrase ... "exact same lineup (inc order) " meant to consider different orders as distinct "lineups".

Comment: Thanks the sorting by name  gives me the alternative table and I have now made some progress so that I can use setdiff to compare specific lineups with first of season, most common etc.